# Python : Result Ranking by classes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, python-3.x

i have three classes separated as below :

## file1.py

```
class one():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 3
        self.h = self.x + self.y
```

## file2.py

```
from file1 import *
class two():
    def __init__(self,coming):
        self.get = coming.h+1
```

## file3.py

```
from file1 import *
from file2 import *
class three():
    def __init__(self,f1,f2):
        self.v1 = f1.h
        self.v2 = f2.get
        print(self.v1)
        print(self.v2)

k = three(two(one()))
```

Whenever should i run the file3.py i need the result look like this way:

```
> 4
> 5
```

but my code give that file2 doesn't return no value,then here my error :

> ~#python file3.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file3.py", line 10, in <module>
    k = three(two(one()))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Comment: Your `three` class expects you to supply two arguments (the third is `self` which is passed in automatically).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that three get 2 arguments instead of 3.
You can change the last line in file3 to:

```
k = three(one(), two(one()))
```

or design the code differently

Comment: i try to order classes like u told me but i get problem in attribute some instance:
error i got when i used `k = three(two(one()),one())`
==>
`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "file3.py", line 10, in <module>

    k = three(two(one()),one())

  File "file3.py", line 5, in __init__

    self.v1 = f1.h

AttributeError: two instance has no attribute 'h'`

Comment: could you provide me example of code that showing how should be this type of class values passing concept ?

Comment: hey, lets say that we have class one,and clas two only !!!!
i wanna pass the value of `h` after such treatment from class two().
whenever i do the import in file1.py then i do import in file2.py
its say `NameError: name 'two' is not defined` !!!
so i face problem when i try to get the value is back to first class after treatment of the second class !!
who could be the code gonna be !!